# Reading point objects from .drw file and drawing lines on panel

Tags: java, arrays, user-interface, file-io, point

I am trying to read **Point objects from .drw file** which contains endpoints of line segments, and draw lines making a square on panel when I run the program. This is what I have got so far. Could you please give some ideas on **how to get the points using array for drawing ?**

// inside the method to read points objects from .drw file

```
try
{
    fos = new FileInputStream("square.drw");
    oos = new ObjectInputStream(fos);

    // creating an  object of Point class
    endPoints = new Point[sampleSize];
    // Creating the Points to put in the array (Deserialize the objects)
    for(int i = 0; i < endPoints.length+1; i++)
    {
        endPoints[i] = (Point) oos.readObject(); 
        endPoints[sampleSize-i+1] = new Point(); // initializing the value before accessing it
        // now setting the values , since the point's aren't null
        endPoints[0].x = x1; // sample points
        endPoints[0].y = y1;
        endPoints[1].x = x2;
        endPoints[1].y = y2;

        // how to initialize every point in the array using for??
    }
}
```

// Actual drawing command

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    // draw parts of the drawing using lineColour
    super.paintComponent(g);
    //Point p = new Point[endPoints];
    int numPoints = endPoints.length;
    for(int i = 0; i < numPoints; i++)
    {
        g.drawLine((int)x1, (int)y1, (int)x2, (int)y2);
    }
}
```

Comment: What programming language is this?

Comment: Alright. I'll edit this time, but please take a look over the formatting of the question before you post; a little extra work on making it nice and clean can go a long way

Comment: Absolutely right!! I will take care of it on later posts. cheers